# Handling name collisions when using pip with several registries

Tags: pip, pypi

I have a private registry that stores `SomePackage` that depends on other packages listed on [pypi](https://pypi.org/). I would like to install `SomePackage` with all its dependencies using [pip](https://pypi.org/project/pip/) but I came across a problem.

At first I used the [--extra-index-url](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#install-extra-index-url) pip option to install `SomePackage`:

```sh
pip install --extra-index-url http://my.package.repo/simple SomePackage
```

But if `SomePackage` also exist on pypi pip will simply [*install the latest version amongst the indexes given*](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3454#issuecomment-180172275) (and not give any priority to my private registry). That seems like a risk to me and [some others](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3454#issuecomment-228635375). So I was wondering if there could be a workaround to prevent the involuntary installation of `SomePackage` from pypi.

I have an idea, but maybe that's a bad one (or maybe it doesn't work as I expect):

```sh
# Install the package from the private registry without its dependencies: 
pip install --no-deps --index-url http://my.package.repo/simple SomePackage
# Then install only its dependencies:
pip install --extra-index-url http://my.package.repo/simple SomePackage
```

This would only work for `SomePackage` but all its dependencies from the private registry will not be "protected" by this approach. **Any other/better idea?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Private Python package management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63320653/private-python-package-management)

Comment: You probably should start by making your private repository the main one, and _PyPI_ the extra one: `python -m pip install --index-url ${PRIVATE_REPO_URL} --extra-index-url ${PYPI_URL}`. And yeah if there are projects with the same name on both repositories, it gets difficult to predict for sure which one is gonna get installed. See my previous comment.

Comment: The linked question is indeed similar, but sadly no answer gives a viable solution yet. Even if the question's suggested idea isn't that bad (ie, register a dummy version of `SomePackage` on Pypi to make sure nobody can usurp it). The advantage is that it's quite easy to automate so I will do that while waiting for a clean solution.

Comment: Best solution is to have and curate your own mirror (using _devpi_ for example).